# What is Closure::bind() in PHP

Tags: php, closures

The PHP manual offers little explanation about [Closure::bind()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) and the example was confusing too.

Here's the code example on the site:

```
class A {
private static $sfoo = 1;
private $ifoo = 2;
}
$cl1 = static function() {
return A::$sfoo;
};
$cl2 = function() {
return $this->ifoo;
};

$bcl1 = Closure::bind($cl1, null, 'A');
$bcl2 = Closure::bind($cl2, new A(), 'A');
echo $bcl1(), "\n";
echo $bcl2(), "\n";
```

What are the parameters for Closure::bind()?

Null was used in the above, and even the "new" keyword was used too, which makes this even more confusing to me.

Comment: Check [bindTo()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php). Here's some more explanations. `bind()` is just static version

Answer (score 6):

If you put the value of `$cl2` as a method of class `A`, the class looks like this:

```
class A {
    public $ifoo = 2;

    function cl2()
    {
        return $this->ifoo;
    }
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
$x = new A();
$x->cl2();
# it prints
2
```

But, because `$cl2` is a closure and not a member of class `A`, the usage code above does not work.

The method [`Closure::bindTo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) allows using the closure as it were a method of class `A`:

```
$cl2 = function() {
    return $this->ifoo;
};

$x = new A();
$cl3 = $cl2->bindTo($x);
echo $cl3();
# it prints 2

$x->ifoo = 4;
echo $cl3();
# it prints 4 now
```

The closure uses the value of `$this` but `$this` is not defined in `$cl2`. 
When `$cl2()` runs, `$this` is `NULL` and it triggers an error (*"PHP Fatal error:  Using `$this` when not in object context"*).

`Closure::bindTo()` creates a new closure but it "binds" the value of `$this` inside this new closure to the object it receives as its first argument.

Inside the code stored in `$cl3`, `$this` has the same value as the global variable `$x`. When `$cl3()` runs, `$this->ifoo` is the value of `ifoo` in object `$x`.

[`Closure::bind()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) is the static version of [`Closure::bindTo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php). It has the same behaviour as `Closure::bindTo()` but requires an additional argument: the first argument must be the closure to bind.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use static version, just try to

```
$cl4 = Closure::bind(function () { return $this->ifoo; }, new A(), 'A');
echo $cl4();
// it returns "2"
```

It is pretty cool, if you wanna update the property of an object, but there is no 'setter' for the property. For example:

```
class Product {
  private $name;
  private $local;
  public function __construct(string $name) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->local = 'usa':
  }
}
$product1 = new Product('nice product');
echo $product1->local;
// it returns 'usa'

$product2 = \Closure::bind(function () {
  $this->local = 'germany';
  return $this;
}, new Product('nice product'), 'Product');
echo $product2->local;
// it returns 'germany'
```